# 3D Studio MAX dxf model to OpenGL and DirectX

Tags: opengl, directx, 3dsmax

**Main Question**

I saw this [Loading and Animating MD5 Models with OpenGL](http://www.3dgep.com/loading-and-animating-md5-models-with-opengl) an old post explaining .md5mesh .md5anim files. Is there any similar alternate mechanisms?

**Additional Questions**

1.) Is there an open source tool or a Plug in for 3ds max to convert a .DXF file to such files which can be used in 3D OpenGL+DirectX game programming.

2.) If I am developing a game in this approach how to make these model files encrypted and make big single file which contains all this file, so that the user cannot crack/hack it?

3.) If I am providing an update via an online gaming server, then how to I update this models and keep it encrypted again?

Comment: If the game can decrypt the data, so can an attacker. There is no absolute "security".

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first question there is an open source library [Assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) which can read such model file, but it comes with an extensive 40+ file types as a generic library which could be a bit bigger in size when you compile. Also it is distributed under 3-clause BSD-License.

If you are creating your own gaming engine, then think about creating your own model design which cannot be parsed by any of the existing library, so it will take time for the hacker to understand it.

Regarding the security concern, I can go with Viklund statement, we can say atleast all security is broken when the games runs in the palyers computer memory.

But think about a non standard public key algorithm which could be a combination of key generated and jumbled with no standard offsets at client machine everytime while user logs in and server provides the current key for decryption which will change next time, So atleast the hacker will take time to decrypt it, and before that you introduce another mechanism and keep changing it.

I would also recomend you change the security key everytime the user enters a map in your game.